# robocopying files from remote machine works in powershell prompt but the same doesn't work from task scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, robocopy

I am tring to copy files from remote through RDP session (\tsclient\C) using powershell code (robocopy).

It works from powershell prompt, but same wont work when I automate through task scheduler.

I get Access Denied error from robocopy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose you are running with different credentials and these credentials do not have access to the resource in question?

Comment: I executed with the same credentials in powershell prompt and it works ... Can't be credentials issue... Only in task scheduler or Jenkins I try to automate it gives that access denied error..

Comment: I suppose you need to set the right credentials in task scheduler. I don't have access to test this on this thin client, but you should run the scheduled task as the correct user. Use UNC paths: \\server\share\path

Comment: Where can I enter the credentials in task scheduler ??

Comment: As I said this computer doesn't have that feature, but [**check this image**](http://configmgrblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ch-check-03.png) and see if it helps.

Comment: I have tested this, problem is my ends machines are connected to 2 different domains, so i  cant run as remote machine user under remote machine domain.

Comment: but this problem doesn't arise when i run from powershell windows, it runs softly with out any issues.